# How to convert the mouse coordinates to correct window coordinates?

Tags: wpf, mouse-position

In .Net, the Window's Left and Top properties are "in relation to the desktop":

> Gets or sets the position of the window's left edge, in relation to the desktop.

Mouse.GetPosition returns the mouse coordinates based on whatever element you pass in:

> Gets the position of the mouse relative to a specified element.

...and PointToScreen converts to "the current coordinate system of the visual".

> Converts a Point in screen coordinates into a Point that represents the current coordinate system of the Visual.

Now, I'm trying to get a window to follow the mouse, but it is not working. When I execute PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this)), I can't set the window's Left and Right properties to the values I get, because it doesn't come out right: When the mouse is at (0,0), the window is indeed set to (0,0). But at the end of the screen (1920, 1080), I get something completely off: something like (roughly 1500, 700).

How can I fix this?

Comment: I removed the tag from your question's title. Please refer to the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to get informed whether you should use tags in the question title.

Comment: Do you have your screen settings at 125% DPI? That could cause this "distortion"

Comment: Yes, that was it... I was sure that Left and Top already take the DPI into account. Used the accepted answer from there to correct the problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/61e93dca-e24c-4953-9719-22ce3f705353/finding-dpi-using-wpf?forum=wpf. Thank you!